# How to convert pandas code using .str and .split to Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote the following code using pandas:

```
df['last_two'] = df['text'].str[-2:]
df['before_hyphen'] = df['text'].str.split('-').str[0]
df['new_text'] = df['before_hyphen'].astype(str) + "-" + df['last_two'].astype(str)
```

But when I run it on a spark dataframe I get the following error:

`TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type`

I know I could just convert the df to pandas, run the code, and then convert it back to a spark df, but I wonder if there's a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the string functions below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'last_two', F.expr('substring(text, -2)')
).withColumn(
    'before_hyphen', F.substring_index('text', '-', 1))
).withColumn(
    'new_text', F.concat_ws('-', 'before_hyphen', 'last_two')
)
```